# How to log the time taken for a unix command?

Tags: shell, unix, time, command

I know my script is going to take more than 10 hours to run. Is there a way to log the time it starts and the time it ends ?

Does the `time` command just time the process or do I get the output of the process that I'm timing ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out with a short-running program?

Comment: i tried `$ time echo 'foobar'`, it outputs `foobar`. But i also want to know of other time/date logging device available.

Comment: `date && time youscript && data` you'll have the start date, the end date, the real world time, the cpu time used in the user space and the cpu time in the system space

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `time` command ([details](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time)):

```
time your_prog
```

If `time` does not fit for you, I would try to log the output of `date` ([details](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date)) before and after the execution of your program, e.g.

```
date > log.txt; your_prog; date >> log.txt
```

Finally, you can also add some formatting (*NOTE: inspired by Raze2dust's answer*):

```
echo "started at: $(date)" > log.txt; your_prog; echo "ended at: $(date)" >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

The `time` command shows how long your process runs:

```
$ time sleep 2

real    0m2.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$
```

`sleep 2` is just a simple process that takes 2 seconds.

To log the current time, use the `date` command.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I get your question. `time <command>` will give the time taken by `<command>`. If you want the actual start and end times to be printed as well, you can do:

```
echo "start time = $(date)"
time <command>
echo "end time = $(date)"
```

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning and ending your script you just need to have **date** commands which will log the information.

```
var1=`date`
echo "Starting of the script $var1" > timing_log.txt

<your code>

var2=`date`
echo "Ending of the script $var2"  >> timing_log.txt
```