# error in calculation execution time of c program?

Tags: c, time.h

can anyone tell me what will happen if I miss double in below lines?

```
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

I was trying to calculate running time of my sorting problem, and forgot to typecast to double. The code ran for almost 90 mins, but the output time printed was "270.000006". Can anyone please help me in figuring out what this 270 signifies??

Also it is sometimes showing "-ve" values. Any solution for this problem.

EDIT - I am sorting 10^9 and 10^10 numbers, so code will be running for hours.

Comment: How do you get end and begin values and what type are they?

Comment: I have used the same code as mentioned below by Debasish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code runs for almost 90 minutes, you will be getting an overflow of clock_t type on 32-bit architecture in under 72 minutes already. I do believe that this is your case.

Comment: is there anyway to avoid this overflow?

Comment: @Anurag In the run you've already done I guess you could try to figure out how much it overflowed (guess it overflowed "once"), and then assume that its your value + the max val. For future fix, you would of course have to save it to a variable which can fit the result.

Comment: @Anurag, that depends on how precise result you are expecting. Since your process is running for hours, my suggestion would be using GetLocalTime and gettimeofday+localtime functions for Windows and Unix respectively.

Comment: @HighPredator. Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using gettimeofday+localtime in Linux, it worked fine initially, but for a code that ran about 6 hours, it gave some error. Any ideas?? Since I am still not sure if this was the reason for error, I am running it again. Any other options which could work??

Comment: @Anurag, what kind of error did you get and how did you use the specified functions?

Comment: @HighPredator. i used it as mentioned in this post -> "http://www.codealias.info/technotes/timing_code_blocks_in_milliseconds_using_gettimeofday_example"

Comment: @Anurag, the code there is not overflow safe either. To make it as accurate as possible you need to do the following:
1) fill the timeval structure at the start and end (as described above)
2) perform nessessary arithmetics with EACH field in that structure (for example: code started at 03.09.2014 20:14 and ended at 04.09.2014 21:25 which means that the code ran exactly 1 day 0 months 0 years 1 hour and 11 minutes, and this data should be converted into minutes or whatever you need. Keep in mind to get a type that will hold result for sure. Otherwise store all as separate values).

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage is:

```
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();
    /* actual task that needs to be monitored */
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
```

You are measuring CPU time here, not the elapsed time which includes I/O time as well. CLOCKS_PER_SEC is a constant which is declared in . The computation needs to be done in floating point arithmetic.
Another alternative to compute timing is to use the time command.

Read [How to log the time taken for a unix command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781264/how-to-log-the-time-taken-for-a-unix-command/18781467#18781467)

Comment: He knows that, this isn't what he asked for. He asked what happens if he **doesn't** save it/typecast to a double.

Comment: If you don't typecast to double, then you lose precision because of the integer arithmetic

Comment: Yes or worse, get overflow, and that's more like an answer to his question.